# What type of database would be good to hold mp3 files

Tags: database, mp3

I'm doing a project that requires me to manipulate pieces of music.
What type of database would be good for me to hold the songs.

Thanks

Comment: but why store store the songs in the database? why not just the filename, path and other metadata of the file and store the file the usual way?

Comment: I'm actually not too sure if storing the files in a database is what I'm looking for. I'm thinking of the issue from the point of people uploading files and then me being able to serve those files quickly. Similar to people uploading video content to youtube.

Comment: Agree with Rahul: a relational database isn't a great way of storing files. A normal filesystem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decide to use Rahul's method.
For more context, I store the files in amazon s3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sql Server and FILESTREAMing.  It's made for this kind of thing.